# Problem installing scipy on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install scipy on a Ubuntu 15.04 virtual box using the command

```
pip install scipy
```

During the installation, however, I get the following error:

```
error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install a fortran compiler?

```
apt-get install gfortran
```

should do the trick.

Occasionally, scipy is packaged in ubuntu, precompiled. You can just do

```
apt-get install python-scipy
```

instead.

Comment: Error: `E: Package 'g77' has no installation candidate`

Comment: But the second suggestion seem to have worked. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, that should've been the `gfortran` package, rather than the `g77` one. It used to be called g77, but apparently that's been changed at some point. (I don't know fortran, so I don't follow how its compilers work...)